# How to copy warning messages in React Native

Tags: react-native

I recently got a warning message appeared on the screen when developing a React Native app. I want to copy that warning message but couldn't find any way to do that. It is possible to copy an error message but not a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can log any warnings and errors in console.

Open separate window on the project directory and run `react-native log-android`

and simply copy error message from console.